# nginx reverse proxy doing loop, how to configure sonarqube https reverse proxy correctly?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https, sonarqube

I am encountering trouble with NGINX doing the HTTPS reverse proxy to sonarqube.

Issue is caused by `proxy_set_header Host $host`, when it set, I keep getting redirected in loop.

When not set, I get redirected to the intranet IP, resulting in DNS failure.

It seems that the application is doing some sort of redirection.

I have not configured anything in app regarding the FQDN.

sonarqube version 6.3.1